# Connection failed: No such file or directory Android Server Error

Tags: php, android, mysql, server, database-connection

[image: The screenshot]

Hey, guys, the above image is a screenshot I took of my epic fail in trying to turn my android device into a server.
I have two separate apps running it, `MariaDB Server` and `Server for PHP`.
So far, I am only trying to connect via LAN, but this happened.
I could connect my database to my `phpMyAdmin's PHP` perfectly but my other websites can't connect to them and are empty when I first checked it out. So my question is, how can I connect my phps which contain:-

```
server= "localhost"
username = "root"
password = ""
database = "myDB"
```

- to the SQL server so that it could contact the database and do what it's supposed to?

I absolutely can not find a manual for those apps to connect on to eachother.
So, please~ I'm begging you! Help a brother out!

Comment: Well what is on line 13? Show the php code.

Comment: `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`

Comment: Show your php code.

Comment: `Connection failed: No such file or directory Android Server Error`. Android server error? Where do you see such a message?

Comment: I tested the connection on my laptop. Found the solution tho. Turns out that i only needed to specify the server.

Comment: well... that guy who edited my question turned out to have broken the initial question itself. So I understand you people's confusion. LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly feel kind of stupid because I did not state my local host specifically therefore i got the error.

Turns out that all I had to do was change to localhost from `server = "localhost"` to `server = "IP:DBServerPORT"` :/
Turns out that if you don't state the port and location of the database port, you'd never connect to it.
It was seriously mind boggling. Took me like 6 hrs straight just to find that one <:/